# download file using ajax in .net web form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using .net web form application in which i am downloading an excel file on button click (using ajax) for that I have created class

```
public class ImunizattionHelper
    {
        public void DownloadFile(String FileTitle,String FilePath)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
            String Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + FileTitle;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
            System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

I am calling this WebMethod on button click

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static void ExportChildernsToExcel(string districtID, string districtName)
        {
            ImunizattionHelper helper = new ImunizattionHelper();
            helper.DownloadFile(districtName + "_Childrens.xlsx", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelBackup/FileToDownload/DistrictwiseChildrens.xlsx").ToString());
        }
```

AJAX

```
 $("#btn_ExportChildernData").click(function () {

             $.ajax({
                 url: 'ExportChildrenToExcel.aspx/ExportChildernsToExcel',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 data: "{ districtID: '" + $("#MainContent_ddlDistrictName option:selected").val() + "', districtName: '" + $("#MainContent_ddlDistrictName option:selected").text() + "' }",
                 success: function (msg) {

                 },
                 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert("responseText=" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + "\n textStatus=" + textStatus + "\n errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
                 }
             });
         })
```

but this creates an error on this code

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

and file download doesn't work. and generate an error.

[Click to See Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKYZJ.png)

but if i use aspx:button and use this code on button click event (I mean without ajax)

```
<asp:Button ID="ExportChildernData" runat="server" Text="Export Childern Data To Excel" OnClick="ExportChildernData_Click" />
 protected void ExportChildernData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            ImunizattionHelper helper = new ImunizattionHelper();
            helper.DownloadFile(ddlDistrictName.SelectedItem.Text+"_Childrens.xlsx", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelBackup/FileToDownload/DistrictwiseChildrens.xlsx").ToString());

        }
```

it works fine

my question is why the file download does not work for ajax ? what is the correct way to download excel file from the specific path in web form application ?

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: @SankarRaj I have attached the error

Comment: You might want to try `Response.Flush()` and then `Response.Close()` instead of `Response.End()` and then maybe throw in a `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`

Comment: @BarryFranklin I used Response.Flush() and then Response.Close() it doesnot generate error, but broser hanged !

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil Did you try `Response.Flush()` and then `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`?

Comment: @BarryFranklin it does not generate error, but browser haged.

Comment: is there any other best way to download excel file in .net web forms application.

Answer (score 1):

How I do it is I save the file in the Cache

```
Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
Using document As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, True)
    WriteExcelFile(ds, document)
End Using
stream.Flush()
stream.Position = 0

If (stream.Length > 0) Then
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("ExcelViewerFilename")
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("ExcelViewerFilename", filename, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Nothing, CacheItemPriority.Normal, Nothing)
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("ExcelViewerContent")
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("ExcelViewerContent", stream, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Nothing, CacheItemPriority.Normal, Nothing)                    
    Dim url As String = "/quotes/ExcelViewer.aspx"
    Response.Redirect(url, False)
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()    
Else
    Throw New HttpException("Error Creating File")
End If
```

and then send them to a new page called "ExcelViewer.aspx" and then in the PreRender I have this:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender

    Dim excelStream As MemoryStream
    Dim excelFilename As String
    excelStream = CType(Cache("ExcelViewerContent"), MemoryStream)
    excelFilename = CType(Cache("ExcelViewerFilename"), String)

    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & excelFilename)
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.BinaryWrite(excelStream.ToArray())
    Response.Flush()
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

End Sub
```

Forgive the VB code. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **FileContentResult** ?

```
public static FileContentResult ExportChildernsToExcel(string districtID, string districtName)
{
    string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelBackup/FileToDownload/DistrictwiseChildrens.xlsx").ToString();

    return File(filePath, "application/vnd.ms-excel", districtName + "_Childrens.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: **FileContentResult** is MVC library. and i have mentioned that i am using **Web Forms** Application